# Cloud Foundry: Node-Red app crashing with 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, node-red

I have created an application in IBM cloud - using the Node-Red starter. The app has been running with no errors for 2 weeks.

I have installed an additional node:"node-red-dashboard":"2.9.6", by adding this in the package.json file.

When deploying within Node-Red, the app crashes with error "Cannot connect to server". 
Then, the page is no longer reachable with error "500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection".

I have tried to restart the app, which allows it to run, again until I deploy again.

[image: Log info]

Comment: To be able to help we really need to see the errors in the log from when you do the deployment as that sounds like it will be the root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an intermittent problem with the toolchain or possibly due to the extra memory requirement placed on the build with the additional node.

Is there a reason why you have not used the manage palette option to install the new nodes?

If you are still getting the error, try increasing the memory allocated to node-red in the manifest.yml file, or try removing the additional node to get node-red to rebuild.